# Value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range error

Tags: java, sql, db2, varchar

I am trying to insert HTML content into a column of my table.

This is my code

```
String Query= "INSERT INTO MyTABLE (id,html) VALUES (?,?)";
insert = conn.prepareStatement(Query); 
insert.setInt(1, id);
insert.setString(2, html);
```

This is my DDL

```
CREATE TABLE MYTAB
(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    HTML VARCHAR (10000) 
);
```

I am getting the below exception while inserting into html field.

```
[8/26/13 4:50:01:344 EDT] 00000796 SystemOut     The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=3.57.110
```

The size of html content is pretty big (it might vary in size so cannot give you the exact size).

The reason I am using `varchar` is, it is easy to pull in the same html content and display on the UI rather than converting it to xml and defining a XML column in place of varchar column.

Can you please help me out to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

How large is `html`? I'm pretty sure you'll get this error when trying to insert more than 10k bytes.

Also I seem to recall a limit on 32k for varchar attributes in DB2 so perhaps you need to look into using a CLOB rather than varchar...

Cheers,

Comment: I am dynamically getting html content from another application as a string, so not sure how big the size is, it is not a file in the disk so I could not measure it. So, using CLOB can I simply query the content as string and display on the UI?

Comment: Sun/Oracle has a [tutorial on LOBs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html#retrieve_clob).